# Why does opencv-python-headless take so long time to complete

Tags: centos, python, opencv

I've noticed that when installing opencv-python-headless using pip3, the process takes a considerable amount of time to complete. I'm curious about the factors that contribute to this lengthy installation time.

OS: CentOS 7